# Computing distance using trignometry

Tags: trigonometry

I need to compute the following distance **Δd** using trigonometry:

[image]

The image contains a green and a blue rectangle. Here are the measures:

```
Width of Green = U
Width of Blue = V
Height of Green and Blue = h
Rotation of Green and Blue along X-axis (clockwise) = θ
Need to compute = Distance between their top-edges after rotation (Δd)
```

Both rectangles were originally aligned to X-axis and their left edges coincided. Then both were rotated θ degrees clockwise around their centers (represented by faint dotted lines). I'm sure this can be done using trigonometry, but having spent the better part of last 2 days, I haven't been able to solve it.

Comment: Is is triangle $D$? You have asked for a distance, which should be $\overline D$.

Comment: @idk: Can u elaborate plz?

Comment: Sure. I'm not a mathematician (rather a CS guy), so bear with me plz.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Yep. The distance was created **because** of rotation and will increase/decrease as theta changes. When theta is zero, the left and top edges of both rectangles will coincide.

Comment: $\theta$ should be indicated on the picture.

Comment: Theta is there. Not shown in the pic, but I have mentioned it in the description. Both rectangles are rotated by theta along x-axis.

Comment: What:does "rotated along the x axis" mean?

Comment: I updated the image to indicate theta.

Comment: You can make $d$ a part of $h$, and continue from there.

Comment: It's not clear where the centre(s) of rotation is/are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is best tackled by looking at the two length $h$ segments that cut the rectangles in halves. I'll call these segments $S_1$ and $S_2$.

1. The distance between the two centres is $v-u\over 2$ (that's the distance between the unrotated $S_1$ and $S_2$).
2. The distance between  $S_1$ and $S_2$ after rotation is therefore ${v-u\over 2}\cos \theta$
3. There is a right triangle with sides $v-u\over 2$, ${v-u\over 2}\cos \theta$, and $\Delta d$. Therefore
   $$(\Delta d)^2+\left({v-u\over 2}\cos \theta\right)^2=\left({v-u\over 2}\right)^2$$
4. It follows $$\Delta d={v-u\over 2}|\sin \theta |$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll be testing it shortly. Along the same lines, can you also think of a way of computing the horizontal delta, i.e. distance between the LEFT edges of the two rectangles?

Comment: Yes, use the same idea but with the other (longer) cut-in-half segments.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Can you indicate S1 and S2 and the right-triangle on my image? I'm having a hard time understanding step 2 of your logic above.

Comment: Draw $S_1$ and $S_2$ after rotation, then the two distances at stake are naturally part of a right triangle involving $\theta$.